# Show flash on Unsuccessful CSV Import in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a working CSV import feature in my Rails app.

**Item.rb**

```
 #CSV Import Function
 def self.import(file)
   CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
     Item.create! row.to_hash
   end  
 end
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
def import
  current_user.items.import(params[:file]) 
  flash[:success] = "Import Successful"
  redirect_to spage3_path 
end
```

This is working great for me. However, when the import is unsuccessful (I have some validations on certain fields on my Item model) the application crashes. In such a scenario I just want to show a flash[:danger] to the user. For that this is how I modified the controller but now every time I am getting flash[:danger]

**items_controller.rb**

```
def import
  if current_user.items.import(params[:file]) 
    flash[:success] = "Import Successful"
    redirect_to spage3_path
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Error Encountered"
    redirect_to spage3_path
  end  
end
```

Please advice where am I getting this wrong. Thanks

Comment: I just wonder how this code work in the first place. First you are calling `import class method` in the `item.rb` on `array of objects`, which is wrong because the `class method` should be called from the `class object itself` For instance - `import method` in the `item.rb` should be called by its class `Item.import`

Comment: Exactly my thoughts - how are you using a class method within an instance of a class?

Comment: The error message would be useful, too

Comment: Not sure if I followed you. I have User model too with has-many relationship with Items. When using ' Item.import(params[:file])' the user_id of the currently loggedin user was not getting assigned to the created Item so I changed it to ' current_user.items.import(params[:file])' so now user_id is being assigned in the DB at time of successful Item creation from CSV. ' current_user' helper function returns the logged in user.

Comment: For CSV import feature I just followed Railscasts #396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.create!` raise an exception if the object validation fails. You've to handle this case to avoid application crashes. 
**You could simply check if the object is valid before to save it.**

- if is valid: save it and continue to parse your CSV
- if not valid: return false and stop parsing CSV

An idea could be:

#### Item.rb

```
 #CSV Import Function
 def self.import(file)
   CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
     item = Item.new(row.to_hash)
     # exit from the block it item is not valid
     return false unless item.valid?

     # save the item only if is valid
     item.save
   end  
 end
```

With this method you can keep your controller as is now.

#### items_controller.rb

```
def import
  if current_user.items.import(params[:file]) 
    flash[:success] = "Import Successful"
    redirect_to spage3_path
  else # when return false show flash[:danger] to the user
    flash[:danger] = "Error Encountered"
    redirect_to spage3_path
  end  
end
```

Comment: Because it lacks context

Comment: Hey @NickGnd it worked for me! Used your code in model and just checked for true/false in my controller to display the correct flash. and cross checked DB to verify Item creation.

Comment: @RichPeck thanks for letting me know. I edited my answer to explain better  my code and how it works.

Comment: @Pushkar I'm glad to be of help :)

Comment: No problem, thanks for being mature about it. I still think the answer lacks context, but if the OP got it working then that's up to him :)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the actual error message, one of your problems is that you're calling `import` as an *instance* method, when you've set it as a *class* method.

The difference between the two is that a *class* method invokes the class, whilst an *instance* method runs within an already invoked class:

```
#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.import
      #class method called by Item.import
   end

   def import
      #instance method called by @item.import
   end
end
```

You'd need the following:

*Although you mention it's working, I really think it's bad practice to call a class method for `current_user.items`...*

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items do
       def import(file)
         CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            item = Item.new row.to_hash #-> this might be best as "self.new" to invoke the instance of Item model
            return item.errors unless item.save 
         end  
       end
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to call:

```
def import
  message = (@file = current_user.items.import(params[:file])) ?  [:notice, "Import Successful"] : [:alert, @file]
  redirect_to.send(spage3_path, "#{message[0]}: #{message[1]}")
end
```

--

There are several things to note here.

Firstly, I have used an [`ActiveRecord Association Extension`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) for the `import` method. I have done this because it's how you're calling it; `current_user.items.import`.

Frankly, I don't know how your current setup is working -- if you called `current_user.items.import` - I would expect the app to kick back an error. You're calling `import` on a collection of the `Item` model, which I would expect to only work with an instance method, definitely not a class.

Secondly, you have to return the exception to your controller. If you're not getting back any exception message, how do you expect to debug? My code gives you how I would return the message, although it might not be correct.

Comment: Thanks @Rich Peck for your detailed explanation. I will try this approach as well.

Comment: Np, it probably needs tweaking a lot but will end up with something more effective than what you have currently

Answer (score 0):

`create!` raises an exception if there is an validation error. Use `create` instead and check the return value:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    return :failed unless Item.create(row.to_hash)
  end
end
```

And change your controller to:

```
def import
  if current_user.items.import(params[:file]) == :failed
    flash[:danger] = "Error Encountered"
  else
    flash[:success] = "Import Successful"
  end  

  redirect_to spage3_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. On successful validation, Item is created in DB and flash[:success] is displayed but on error I am seeing flash[:success] instead of flash[:danger] and item is not created in DB. Any advice ?